# Floating point exception C code

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, wait

The given code produces a Floating point exception ,Can anyone tell me what this caused by?

```
int play(t_env* env, t_pos* pos)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int     ret;
    t_data  data;   
    int     status;

    pos->addx = 1;
    pos->addy = 0;
    pos->x = 2 + rand() % data.row;
    pos->y = 2 + rand() % data.col;
    pid = getpid();
    ret = waitpid(WAIT_ANY, &status, WNOHANG);

    if (ret == -1)
    {
            id_print_str("Error during waiting stat");
            exit(1);
    }
    while (pos->x != data.row)
    {
            tputs(tgoto(env->cm, pos->x, pos->y), 1, id_put);
            id_print_char('1');
            sleep(1);
            pos->x = pos->x + pos->addx;
            pos->y = pos->y + pos->addy;

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you referring to I just see some code.   ?

Comment: well, when i compile, I get a floating point exception once i run the compiled program

Comment: Then run it under a debugger and figure out what line is throwing the exception. How do you know the function you've posted is the cause?

Comment: because its been working until the very moment I added that wait function, that I used for the first time in my life. So i was wondering if that was the right use.

Comment: as well as the rand...data.row and data.col are both supposedly 70.

Comment: There isn't any floating point calculations in the code you supplied.  The cause of the exception is elsewhere.

Comment: The program exits right after that first rand... Why?

Comment: This function does not seem to use floating point at all. It is not clear how it could possibly trigger a floating point exception. Can you demonstrate that it indeed does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the given code,I suppose, Its only possible here,

```
pos->x = 2 + rand() % data.row;
pos->y = 2 + rand() % data.col;
```

make sure that `data.row` and `data.col` are non-zero. Or else, the problem might be somewhere else.